# Change Value Within Loop but only once

Tags: python-3.x

I have a loop I’m running, it’s about 6 different functions joined together, so it’s a little confusing to me but they all seem to be working but this end part.

After the loop is complete it needs to change the answer to a different value depending on the below rules.

I’m quite new to python and programming in general and think I must be missing something.
Currently my code appears to be running properly for example if dow was 0 then dow becomes 6 which is correct. But then the elif runs and makes it 5 which breaks everything, help.

```
if dow == 0:
    dow =6
elif dow == 1:
    dow = 0
elif dow == 2:
    dow = 1
elif dow == 3:
    dow = 2
elif dow == 4:
    dow = 3
elif dow == 5:
    dow = 4
elif dow == 6:
    dow = 5
```

Comment: This `if`-`elif` block is inside the loop?

Comment: From the description, I understand that you want to change the value only in the first iteration and not in the next.

In that case maybe you should use a separate variable name and use it instead of reusing `dow`. If that is not an option, a crude way would be to use a variable(a flag) to indicate if it's the first loop or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you can also just replace this loop with:

```
dow = (dow - 1) % 7
```

Comment: Wow, that’s way easier, my brain just isn’t so good at thinking with a programming brain yet, thank you so much big_bad_bison.

Comment: @MatthewHutchins You'll get there, whenever you're making long conditionals like this try thinking of the logic/math behind it and how you can make it scale-able. Imagine if instead of 7 values you had to account for 1 million values.

Comment: Ah I see now, hot damn is that useful, I have a problem that has 2042 values that have to be altered, it’s some stock exchange data, this is going to make that so easy now yay.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Deepak Gouda, that fixed it, thank you, so simple.
Changed dow to dow1

```
dow1 = (stdcheck/juniper)%7

if dow1 == 0:
  dow =6
elif dow1 == 1:
  dow = 0
elif dow1 == 2:
  dow = 1
elif dow1 == 3:
  dow = 2
elif dow1 == 4:
  dow = 3
elif dow1 == 5:
  dow = 4
elif dow1 == 6:
  dow = 5
```